# Super High School Level Crossword

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

*Note: This crossword contains objectively more references to Japanese popular media than necessary. Does that fill you with despair? Upupupu...*

[image: 25x25 crossword grid]

#### Clues

```
Across
1. Hairstyle more popular in the '80s-'90s
7. Sigh of relaxation
10. "____monogatari", featuring popular songs "Kimi no Shiranai Monogatari" and "Renai Circulation"
14. Monsters that fear the light, notably in the text adventure "Zork"
19. Big sis, in Japanese
21. Optical diaphragm
23. Eponymous twin-tailed sharpshooter from "____ the Scarlet Ammo"
24. Berate loudly
26. 1920's-30's design style
27. Gov. division
28. Habit wearers
29. Skintight garment
30. The One True God of "No Game No Life"
31. "Yuri!!! on ___", featuring figure skating
33. Bean used to make miso
35. _____ time's the charm
37. Work on a costume, perhaps
39. "Pokémon" protagonist Ketchum
40. Speed ratio for Koro-sensei of "Assassination Classroom"
42. Javascript decoding function whose inverse is its first and last characters swapped
43. Last word of "My Little Sister Can't Be This Cute" in Japanese
46. Danganronpa, the original
53. Pine (for)
55. Storm's centre
56. Like Phoenix Wright, as an attorney
57. Stretching rectangular frame used for torture
58. Torture ______
59. It may precede a storm
61. Security extensions for the system which converts domain names into IP addresses, in short
64. Boot from power
65. Corpse
66. Close relationship
67. Stay fresh
68. Soft drink notably sold in a marble-containing bottle
70. First word of "My Little Sister Can't Be This Cute" in Japanese
71. N.Y. summer clock setting
72. Choose
73. Its states are NSW, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC and WA
74. Online multiplayer game played at The International, in short
75. 1-8 on a chessboard, conventionally
77. Affirmative votes
79. :: : as :: : : ____
81. Number of active idols in "The iDOLM@STER" originally
82. And so forth, briefly
83. Spoke (up)
88. "Heavy Rotation" idol group ___48
90. Mingle (with)
93. French for "tire" and prefix for how one may describe a tire
94. e.g. "Danganronpa 3" but not "Danganronpa V3"
95. Type of arrest commonly seen in "Death Note"
99. (*) What each of sixteen characters can be, in more than one sense?
101. Magical : Index :: Scientific : _______
103. S for a tee
104. Lock and ____
106. Sauville's continent in "GOSICK"
107. Left half of a physics notation
108. Record material
109. Memory stick, briefly
110. Satisfied (a requirement)
111. Pro ____ (fairly shared)
114. Long story, as in "Kirby's Epic ____"
118. Scratchy's partner in "The Simpsons"
120. It might be sold "on the bone"
122. Scrabble player's favourite shrub
123. Childish verbal tic of Yuudachi from "KanColle"
124. Fleur-de-___
127. Japanese broadcaster, referenced in the title "Welcome to the ___"
128. Cooks over a fire
130. Sledding sport
131. ____-chef (kitchen's second in command)
132. Confines, in a way
134. Sort of following from a dedicated fanbase
135. King and owner of stables in a Herculean labour
137. ____'s Peak Academy (46-Across setting)
138. Deserving (of)
139. "Ano____: The Flower We Saw That Day"
140. Yukizome Chisa ("Danganronpa 3") and Tokiha ___ ("___-HiME") voice actress Nakahara
141. An "itasha" is this moe-fied
142. 89-Down's Ultimate Inventor Miu
143. Danganronpa, the spin-off
151. Dating ___
152. Light follower?
155. Kiss and cuddle, slangily
156. "GochiUsa" creator and Japanese for love
157. Nevertheless
158. Ruminated
160. Wound with a blade
162. Shooting location
163. "Zero Time Dilemma" canine
165. Pollywog
169. "Vidi", in "Veni, vidi, vici"
172. Teen detective Nancy
174. Like an eroge
178. Role of 89-Down's Kirumi Tojo, at times
179. Effortlessness
180. Long story, as in "Excel ____"
181. "Umbrella" singer from Barbados
182. Cowboy's greeting
183. Prison, informally
184. "Nyanpasu~" manga's first or second word, with "Biyori"
185. You might use a match or find a match on it

Down
1. Siege defense feature
2. Pre-riot dissatisfaction
3. Phi or sigma, e.g.
4. Called the shots
5. Suffix with Japan
6. Middle word of a futile game
7. ____-de-camp (military assistant)
8. "We ___!" ("One Piece" first opening song)
9. Body parts swung by "Popotan" characters in a memetic GIF
10. Tarski's partner in a geometric "paradox"
11. "To ___ Majutsu no Index" ("A Certain Magical Index")
12. Relatives, collectively
13. First round wind in mahjong
14. Super Danganronpa
15. Groove
16. "Toki wo Kizamu ___" (lit. "A Song to Pass the Time") from "CLANNAD ~After Story~"
17. Part picked in many an ASMR work
18. Norm (abbr.), as in a C++ library
20. White _____ (silenceable statements in "Danganronpa")
22. Step forcefully
24. Cut, as a throat
25. "Yuki Yuna is a ____"
32. Inverse of ord, in Python
34. "Huzzah!"
36. "Link" an enemy using 143-Across' megaphone gun, for example
38. Dual _____ (use two weapons at once)
39. ___ of consent
41. Blue-haired Sairenji from "To Love-Ru", or singer Luna of "Sword Art Online" and "Saekano" fame
43. Innocent
44. Bridged two electrodes, in a way
45. Lifeless, motionless
47. Physical high school class
48. Apt rhyme for "clasp"
49. Coolers, briefly
50. Classmate, e.g.
51. Broken item that starts the events of "Ouran High School Host Club"
52. Birth month of Kyoko Kirigiri and Sonia Nevermind (abbr.)
54. Neon Genesis unit, in short
58. Like Gundham Tanaka's Devas of Destruction, in 14-Down
59. Plagiarise
60. Up the ____ (raise the stakes)
61. See 91-Down
62. Avian home
63. Ultimate chord progression
64. "Seek a way ___!" (Zero Escape prompt)
65. Agree (with)
66. ___ constrictor
67. 2008 sci-fi series about the digitisation of memory
69. Primary mob enemies of 143-Across
75. Export, for a video
76. ___ humble pie (admitted one's mistake with humility)
78. With melancholy
80. "Yowza!"
81. Info coming later (abbr.)
84. Ornament by embedding
85. What "Porco" means in Studio Ghibli's "Porco Rosso"
86. Kangaroo's partner on a coat of arms
87. Lair
89. New Danganronpa
91. With 61-Down, top of sixteen races in "No Game No Life"
92. 92FS firearm brand for Yurippe of "Angel Beats"
93. ___ talk (inspirational speech)
95. .xls alternative
96. Mioda Ibuki (14-Down) and Haramura Nodoka ("Saki") voice actress Koshimizu
97. Shinichi's love interest Mouri in "Meitantei Conan" ("Case Closed")
98. Hen's sounds
100. Parenthesised word in many a Neon Genesis movie
102. Subside
105. US clothing line ___Kosh B'Gosh
112. "KonoSuba" goddess of water
113. Classifying labels
115. Per item, informally
116. Debauchee
117. ___ America ("Danganronpa" English-language publisher)
119. Doujin murder mystery "Higurashi When ____ Cry" ("Higurashi no Naku Koro ni")
120. Grinding teeth
121. ___ crow (admit one's mistake with humility)
124. "Jabberwocky" poet Carroll
125. Ruruka Andou ("Danganronpa 3") and Rem ("Re:Zero") voice actress Minase
126. Debate _____, gameplay mechanic of 89-Down
128. Pipsqueak
129. ____ up (recaps)
130. Alderaan princess
131. "I'm _____, I was born stupid" (Sticker with 14-Down's limited edition)
133. Texter's "right now"
134. Lo-___ (lite)
136. ___ moe (tsundere's charm point)
137. Japanese yes
139. "Steins;Gate" illustrator and member of "supercell"
141. Software-made SFX
144. Solution
145. Symbol preceding 36-Down in a multimedia sci-fi franchise
146. "Good grief!"
147. "Fire Emblem" protagonist playable in "Super Smash Bros. Brawl"
148. Palindromic spinner
149. "The ______ of Zelda"
150. "Pokémon" season 1 cruiser, sharing its name with the mother of the Virgin
153. Christmas season
154. Technology operator
159. Gets punished, in "Danganronpa"
161. Cereal ingredient, often
162. Cob or pen
164. Animal that forms the appearance of 69-Down
165. Tsundere's sound of annoyance
166. VR game where you can fly, in SAO
167. Lawn condensation
168. Unnecessarily lengthen
170. Took a chair
171. "My Youth Romantic Comedy Is Wrong, ___ Expected"
173. Alter ___
175. Sunk one's teeth into
176. Four or death in Japanese
177. Prison, informally
```

#### Across TEXT (for use with [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/))

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE V2>
<TITLE>
Super High School Level Crossword
<AUTHOR>
Sp3000
<COPYRIGHT>
For Puzzling Stack Exchange
<SIZE>
25x25
<GRID>
XXXXXX..XXX..XXXX...XXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX
XXX...XXX.XXXX..XXXXX....
.XXX.XXX...XXXX..XXXX.XXX
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..XXXXX
...XXX..XXX...XXXX.XXXXXX
.XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX..XXX.XXX
XXX..XXX...XXXX.XXXXX....
XXXX.XXXX.XXX...XXX.XXXXX
...XXX..XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX..XXX...
XXXXX.XXX...XXX.XXXX.XXXX
....XXXXX.XXXX...XXX..XXX
XXX.XXX..XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXX.
XXXXXX.XXXX...XXX..XXX...
XXXXX..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
XXX.XXXX..XXXX...XXX.XXX.
....XXXXX..XXXX.XXX...XXX
XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXX...XXXX..XXX..XXXXXX
<ACROSS>
Hairstyle more popular in the '80s-'90s
Sigh of relaxation
"____monogatari", featuring popular songs "Kimi no Shiranai Monogatari" and "Renai Circulation"
Monsters that fear the light, notably in the text adventure "Zork"
Big sis, in Japanese
Optical diaphragm
Eponymous twin-tailed sharpshooter from "____ the Scarlet Ammo"
Berate loudly
1920's-30's design style
Gov. division
Habit wearers
Skintight garment
The One True God of "No Game No Life"
"Yuri!!! on ___", featuring figure skating
Bean used to make miso
_____ time's the charm
Work on a costume, perhaps
"Pokemon" protagonist Ketchum
Speed ratio for Koro-sensei of "Assassination Classroom"
Javascript decoding function whose inverse is its first and last characters swapped
Last word of "My Little Sister Can't Be This Cute" in Japanese
Danganronpa, the original
Pine (for)
Storm's centre
Like Phoenix Wright, as an attorney
Stretching rectangular frame used for torture
Torture ______
It may precede a storm
Security extensions for the system which converts domain names into IP addresses, in short
Boot from power
Corpse
Close relationship
Stay fresh
Soft drink notably sold in a marble-containing bottle
First word of "My Little Sister Can't Be This Cute" in Japanese
N.Y. summer clock setting
Choose
Its states are NSW, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC and WA
Online multiplayer game played at The International, in short
1-8 on a chessboard, conventionally
Affirmative votes
:: : as :: : : ____
Number of active idols in "The iDOLM@STER" originally
And so forth, briefly
Spoke (up)
"Heavy Rotation" idol group ___48
Mingle (with)
French for "tire" and prefix for how one may describe a tire
e.g. "Danganronpa 3" but not "Danganronpa V3"
Type of arrest commonly seen in "Death Note"
(*) What each of sixteen characters can be, in more than one sense?
Magical : Index :: Scientific : _______
S for a tee
Lock and ____
Sauville's continent in "GOSICK"
Left half of a physics notation
Record material
Memory stick, briefly
Satisfied (a requirement)
Pro ____ (fairly shared)
Long story, as in "Kirby's Epic ____"
Scratchy's partner in "The Simpsons"
It might be sold "on the bone"
Scrabble player's favourite shrub
Childish verbal tic of Yuudachi from "KanColle"
Fleur-de-___
Japanese broadcaster, referenced in the title "Welcome to the ___"
Cooks over a fire
Sledding sport
____-chef (kitchen's second in command)
Confines, in a way
Sort of following from a dedicated fanbase
King and owner of stables in a Herculean labour
____'s Peak Academy (46-Across setting)
Deserving (of)
"Ano____: The Flower We Saw That Day"
Yukizome Chisa ("Danganronpa 3") and Tokiha ___ ("___-HiME") voice actress Nakahara
An "itasha" is this moe-fied
89-Down's Ultimate Inventor Miu
Danganronpa, the spin-off
Dating ___
Light follower?
Kiss and cuddle, slangily
"GochiUsa" creator and Japanese for love
Nevertheless
Ruminated
Wound with a blade
Shooting location
"Zero Time Dilemma" canine
Pollywog
"Vidi", in "Veni, vidi, vici"
Teen detective Nancy
Like an eroge
Role of 89-Down's Kirumi Tojo, at times
Effortlessness
Long story, as in "Excel ____"
"Umbrella" singer from Barbados
Cowboy's greeting
Prison, informally
"Nyanpasu~" manga's first or second word, with "Biyori"
You might use a match or find a match on it
<DOWN>
Siege defense feature
Pre-riot dissatisfaction
Phi or sigma, e.g.
Called the shots
Suffix with Japan
Middle word of a futile game
____-de-camp (military assistant)
"We ___!" ("One Piece" first opening song)
Body parts swung by "Popotan" characters in a memetic GIF
Tarski's partner in a geometric "paradox"
"To ___ Majutsu no Index" ("A Certain Magical Index")
Relatives, collectively
First round wind in mahjong
Super Danganronpa
Groove
"Toki wo Kizamu ___" (lit. "A Song to Pass the Time") from "CLANNAD ~After Story~"
Part picked in many an ASMR work
Norm (abbr.), as in a C++ library
White _____ (silenceable statements in "Danganronpa")
Step forcefully
Cut, as a throat
"Yuki Yuna is a ____"
Inverse of ord, in Python
"Huzzah!"
"Link" an enemy using 143-Across' megaphone gun, for example
Dual _____ (use two weapons at once)
___ of consent
Blue-haired Sairenji from "To Love-Ru", or singer Luna of "Sword Art Online" and "Saekano" fame
Innocent
Bridged two electrodes, in a way
Lifeless, motionless
Physical high school class
Apt rhyme for "clasp"
Coolers, briefly
Classmate, e.g.
Broken item that starts the events of "Ouran High School Host Club"
Birth month of Kyoko Kirigiri and Sonia Nevermind (abbr.)
Neon Genesis unit, in short
Like Gundham Tanaka's Devas of Destruction, in 14-Down
Plagiarise
Up the ____ (raise the stakes)
See 91-Down
Avian home
Ultimate chord progression
"Seek a way ___!" (Zero Escape prompt)
Agree (with)
___ constrictor
2008 sci-fi series about the digitisation of memory
Primary mob enemies of 143-Across
Export, for a video
___ humble pie (admitted one's mistake with humility)
With melancholy
"Yowza!"
Info coming later (abbr.)
Ornament by embedding
What "Porco" means in Studio Ghibli's "Porco Rosso"
Kangaroo's partner on a coat of arms
Lair
New Danganronpa
With 61-Down, top of sixteen races in "No Game No Life"
92FS firearm brand for Yurippe of "Angel Beats"
___ talk (inspirational speech)
.xls alternative
Mioda Ibuki (14-Down) and Haramura Nodoka ("Saki") voice actress Koshimizu
Shinichi's love interest Mouri in "Meitantei Conan" ("Case Closed")
Hen's sounds
Parenthesised word in many a Neon Genesis movie
Subside
US clothing line ___Kosh B'Gosh
"KonoSuba" goddess of water
Classifying labels
Per item, informally
Debauchee
___ America ("Danganronpa" English-language publisher)
Doujin murder mystery "Higurashi When ____ Cry" ("Higurashi no Naku Koro ni")
Grinding teeth
___ crow (admit one's mistake with humility)
"Jabberwocky" poet Carroll
Ruruka Andou ("Danganronpa 3") and Rem ("Re:Zero") voice actress Minase
Debate _____, gameplay mechanic of 89-Down
Pipsqueak
____ up (recaps)
Alderaan princess
"I'm _____, I was born stupid" (Sticker with 14-Down's limited edition)
Texter's "right now"
Lo-___ (lite)
___ moe (tsundere's charm point)
Japanese yes
"Steins;Gate" illustrator and member of "supercell"
Software-made SFX
Solution
Symbol preceding 36-Down in a multimedia sci-fi franchise
"Good grief!"
"Fire Emblem" protagonist playable in "Super Smash Bros. Brawl"
Palindromic spinner
"The ______ of Zelda"
"Pokemon" season 1 cruiser, sharing its name with the mother of the Virgin
Christmas season
Technology operator
Gets punished, in "Danganronpa"
Cereal ingredient, often
Cob or pen
Animal that forms the appearance of 69-Down
Tsundere's sound of annoyance
VR game where you can fly, in SAO
Lawn condensation
Unnecessarily lengthen
Took a chair
"My Youth Romantic Comedy Is Wrong, ___ Expected"
Alter ___
Sunk one's teeth into
Four or death in Japanese
Prison, informally
```

---

Ultimate hint:

> If you think this crossword is *hard*, that's *fine*, but the grid could do with more...

Comment: Gah, you HAD to release this when I'm at board game night. (Also, you're a weeb.)

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55374/let-us-all-join-the-party-for-hope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuing from Mike's solution, we notice that

> the central clue tells us that "sixteen characters can be blackened".

What does that mean?

> We can "blacken" characters by replacing them with the letter B - the abbreviation for "black" in chess and pencil grades, among other things.

Doing this gives:

> [image]
>  **MAKE YOUR ARGUMENT**, a phrase that appears on-screen in the Danganronpa games right before every trial segment.

Answer (score 10):

Domo arigato Mr. Sp3000!

> [image]

If there's a second secret to find (like in the [Sea O Letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53644/a-sea-o-letters)) then I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

partial solve,
I dont know how to upload .puz file

> [image]